# Adding months to existing date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I have an existing date column, how can I add a certain number of months to that date?

Example, something like this

```
UPDATE TrackingData
SET DATEADD(mm, 18, ExpiryDate)    -- ExpiryDate is the date column I want to add the months to
WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very close...

```
UPDATE TrackingData
SET ExpiryDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 18, ExpiryDate)
WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

Comment: Upvote for using the **intuitive** and **immediately clear** `MONTH` indicator, instead of the obscure, unintuitive `mm` (is that month? minutes? milliseconds?)

Comment: @marc_s - I know it not going to make any difference in Output but Will it that make any difference in terms of performance just curious.

Comment: @NoDisplayName: no, there's no performance difference - but a **HUGE** difference in **clarity and maintainability** in the long run!

Comment: @marc_s - Here after I will also use `Month` instead of `MM` and thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

Just Specify the `column (ExpiryDate)` in `SET` which has to be updated

```
UPDATE TrackingData
SET    ExpiryDate = Dateadd(MONTH, 18, ExpiryDate)
WHERE  EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE TrackingData

SET ExpiryDate = DATEADD(mm,18,ExpiryDate)--ExpiryDate represents the date field I want to add the months to

WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```